# Is it possible to assign an integer value to a positional parameter in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I am reading the zsh's manual and I know that I can assign the integer value to a parameter by:

```
(( val = 1 ))
```

And if I am calling a script, and my first parameter is an integer like `./scirpt.zsh $((val))`, how can I refer to it in my script to do some arithmetic processes like reassignment, comparison,etc? I hope the code like following:

```
#!/bin/zsh

(( {1} = $1++ ))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In zsh, the array variable [`argv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-argv) is an alternative way to access the positional parameters. So:

```
((argv[1]++))
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement [@Gilles' answer](/a/600858), you can also assign values to positional parameters *outside* of arithmetic expressions with `1=value` for instance, so here to increment the first positional parameter, you could also do:

```
1=$(($1 + 1))
```

But strictly speaking, if `$1` may contain an arbitrary arithmetic expression as opposed to just a literal numerical constant (such as `a=++x` for instance), you'd need `1=$((($1) + 1))` for the two to be equivalent¹. Compare:

```
$ x=4 zsh -c '((argv[1]++)); echo "$1 $a $x"' zsh a=++x
6 5 5
$ x=4 zsh -c '1=$(($1 + 1)); echo "$1 $a $x"' zsh a=++x
6 6 5
$ x=4 zsh -c '1=$((($1) + 1)); echo "$1 $a $x"' zsh a=++x
6 5 5
```

That's one of the common problems with using `$var` instead of `var` inside arithmetic expressions. With `$1`, you obviously can't use `1`, but with `zsh`, you can use `argv[1]`.

Beside those convoluted cases, the problem manifests itself in real life cases with things like:

```
$ zsh -c 'echo $((1-$1))' zsh -3
zsh:1: bad math expression: operator expected at `3'
```

As that becomes `1--3` which is an incorrect usage of the `--` operator. You'd work around it with either:

```
$ zsh -c 'echo $((1 - $1))' zsh -3
4
$ zsh -c 'echo $((1-($1)))' zsh -3
4
$ zsh -c 'echo $((1-argv[1]))' zsh -3
4
```

(though again, the first one would give different results for values like `1 + 1`).

---

<sup>¹If we ignore the fact that `((argv[1]++))` returns a non-zero exit status when `$1` was resolving to 0</sup>